# what to say when internet is very fast/slow?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, sentence-construction, expressions

I can obvious just say the internet is fast/slow, but I want some different expression when it is/becomes super-fast/slow . (something like the internet flies? Is there a proper way of saying that?)

Comment: Cranking up, Zooming around.

Comment: This may be slightly specialized, but I think referring to the presence or absence of “lag” (latency) is probably your best bet. The adjective “laggy” may also come in handy. Examples: “Wow, there's _no lag_ right now!”, or “Our Internet (connection) is really _laggy_ at the moment.”

Comment: If you're just looking be more emphatic, you can use adjectives before “fast” or “slow” to communicate that the speed is more extreme in either direction. Examples: “The Internet is _blazing_ fast right now.”, “... _brutally_ slow...”, or countless other emphatic adjectives or adverbs.

Comment: My internet is slower than a herd of snails traveling through peanut butter

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's a standard phrase to refer to fluctuations in internet speed (aside from the technical terminology used by internet service providers, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking for).

As such, any word which conveys speed (or a lack thereof) could be used. I'm more familiar with such a word being an adjective though (rather than a verb, as you've used). Also, I usually hear references to one's own internet connection described as '*my* internet' rather than 'the internet'.

For example:

> My internet's crawling tonight.

or

> My internet's flying!

However, people will often just use

> My internet's being really slow/fast.

as you mentioned.

Answer (score -4):

When Net is slow, I say it's dead.

Comment: I'm sure it's just differences of personal usage, but if I used 'dead', I'd be wanting to convey that it was down altogether.